# gst-launch 1.0 window resize

Tags: gstreamer-1.0, gst-launch, gst-launch-1.0

Here I have udp stream sender by gst-launch 1.0:

`gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location="./venom-trailer-3_h720p.mov" ! qtdemux ! rtph264pay pt=96 config-interval=-1 ! udpsink host=face=eth0 -e3 port=5001 multicast-if`

and here is my receiver command:

`DISPLAY=:0 gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc uri=udp://232.255.23.23:5001 port=5001 ! application/x-rtp, payload=96 ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! queue ! avdec_h264 ! xvimagesink udpsrc`

My question is how to change position and size of window in receiver. According to this 
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-plugins/html/gst-plugins-base-plugins-ximagesink.html

I have to change `ximagesink` values but i get

`WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no property "width" in element "xvimagesink0"`

Answer (score 0):

According to the link you posted, the element ximage sink does NOT have a property `width`, it has a property called `window-width` instead.